# Upload site template PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, solution-package, site-template

I am using SharePoint 2013 and i want to create some spweb from a site template...

I have created a site and added my desired content and i saved that site as template, then went to solution gallery and downloaded the `.wsp` file.

Now, i need to create a new site collection with some subsites which are based on that template, and to do so i think need to upload the `.wsp` file to the solution gallery the way i can find the newly saved template, and i need to do that from PowerShell !

I tried 2 ways,

First,

I tried to add-spsolution and install-spsolution like following

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $SPIntranetTemplateFilePath
Install-SPSolution -Identity SPITemplateFile.wsp -CompatibilityLevel 15 -force
```

but i don't find the .wsp in the solution gallery and the template is not in templates list...

I tried to use Install-SPWebTemplate but this command is not recognized as a cmdlet in my PowerShell (I have added `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`)

I have used this too

```
## SharePoint DLL 
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
```

Can anyone help me to use my WspFile the way i can create subsites based on my template ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to add the template into a site.

1. Use the UI and upload it (directly going to solution gallery)
2. or try to use these [Add-SPUserSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607715.aspx) and [Install-SPUserSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607653.aspx).

Comment: As i mentioned it i want it from powerShell then I already mentioned too that i tried Add-SPSolution and InsTall-SPSolution and did not work... can help me more and tell me why it does not work?

Comment: my commands are different then you already tried...please try those...add-spusersolution

Comment: the wsp file is added to the solution gallery and the template appears in custom templates list (on teh U.I) BUT does not figure on the templates list when i do Get-SPWebTemplate in PowerShell... why do you think is this heppening?

Comment: what you mean, does not figure on the templates list?

Comment: when i execute the command Get-SPWebTemplate the newly deployed .wsp template does not exist... this is the most imporgtant thing because i want to get its id or name to generate new subsites based on that template

Comment: is that template/solution is activated and also try SPWeb.GetAvailableWebTemplates method.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getavailablewebtemplates(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: OK, Thank you very much for your help. the last thing really i need to know is : why it didn't work when i used add-SPSolution ?? e.g. what are the differences except the fact that add-SPUserSolution is for sandboxed solutions???

Comment: that's what i believe, saved as template(wsp) fall into the sandbox solution...

Comment: how to create a subsite from the above emntioned site template? is there any powershell for this?, am stuck with the similar kind of scenario,am unable to see the customtemplate in the new sub site page? @WaqasSarwarMVP

Comment: @prasadwt You can use something like `$template= $site.GetWebTemplates($locale)|?{$_.Title -eq "templateTitle"}`. This can then be used via $template parameter in the `$site.AllWebs.Add()`-Method