# Activate all site templates

Tags: 2010

I need to activate all deactivated custom site templates in a site collection. I tried with the GUI, but "Activate" is disabled when I select multiple items.
What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Helpful link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111609/upload-site-template-powershell